# Android Maps Utils: How to change default GoogleMap clustering zoom level

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Hao, stackoverflow!
I'm using Android Maps Utils to cluster markers, it's a little bit tricky, but generally ok.

Map Utils has some default value, on which zoom level it splits one cluster to several clusters or markers. I just need to do it earlier i.e. i need to start split items on bigger zoom level rather then default value.

I think it's not about shoudRenderAsCluster(cluster), cause this callback called already with splitted clusters after this default zoom level.

I've tried GridBasedAlgorithm (really strange behavior when zooming out) and NonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm (it seems default).

Thanks!

Comment: Have you experimented with 'setMaxDistanceBetweenClusteredItems' ?  The Algorithm interface defines this so each implementation should support it in some way relevant to the implementation.